# array of string in bash sed command

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

for loop is looping only one time for sed. Anything missing in the below code,

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=("string1" "string2" "string3" string4")
arraylength=${#array[@]}
for (( i=o; i<${arraylength}; i++))
 do
   dest="${array[$i]}"
   echo $dest
   sed -i 's/name1/'"$dest"'/g' /home/input.txt
   cp /home/input.txt  /home/inputmodified.txt
 done
```

in above code while echo printing all the string of array, but in file /home/input.txt only first string is replacing.

```
echo $dest
string1
string2
string3
string4
cat /home/input.txt
this is string1
this is string1
```

I need data to be like

```
this is string1
this is string1
this is string2
this is string2
this is string3
this is string3
this is string4
this is string4
```

Comment: You have at least one typo: `string4"` should be `"string4"` and `i=o` should be `i=0`. Using a linter such as https://www.shellcheck.net/ may help you avoid errors like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first iteration of the loop, the `sed -i` command replaces all occurrences of "name1" in the file with "string1". On the second, third, etc iterations, there are no occurrences of "name1" in the file (they've all been replaced with "string1"), so `sed` doesn't find anything to replace.

Rather than doing in-place modification of the original file (`-i`), I think what you want is to output a modified version *but not change the original*. Also, using `cp` doesn't add to the output file, it *replaces* it, so the only thing that'll be there is what's copied in the last iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=("string1" "string2" "string3" "string4")
for value in "${array[@]}"; do
    sed "s/name1/$value/g" /home/input.txt
done >/home/inputmodified.txt
```

Other changes I made:

- To iterate over the contents of an array, you don't need to figure out the array indexes, just use `for value in "${array[@]}"` to get the elements directly.
- I simplified the quoting on the `sed` command string. There wasn't anything there that required single-quotes, so putting the whole thing in double-quotes is fine. If there's anything really weird in the actual search string, you might have to change it back (or escape the funny characters).
- Each `sed` command outputs the modified version of the file to its standard output; the `>` redirection after `done` redirects standard output for the entire loop to the file, so all iterations get added to that.
- ...but that meant I had to remove the `echo $value` (which should be `echo "$value"`, anyway), because it'd be added to the output file along with the output from `sed`. If you want that as debug output, send it to standard error rather than standard output with `echo "$value" >&2`.

BTW, I recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), since it'll catch a lot of common shell scripting mistakes.